# Run TestNG test sequentially with invocationCount

Tags: java, testng, method-invocation

I have a long-running @test annotated method that I need to run repeatedly and I achieve this with `invocationCount`.

When I hard code the value e.g. `invocationCount=10` then it runs succesfully, running tests 1 - 10 sequentially, i.e. it waits for the method to complete and then starts the next invocation.

However, I need to be able to alter the `invocationCount` value at runtime so have implemented the `IAnnotationTransformer` interface to achieve this, passing in the key, value pair at runtime. However, this has the effect of running the tests in parallel.  I've provided a simplified version here:

TestNG.xml:

```
<suite name="Run tests sequentially" verbose="1" thread-count="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">

    <listeners>
        <listener
                class-name="com.tests.utils.AnnotationTransformerImpl"/>
    </listeners>

    <test name="invocation-test-synchronised" parallel="false">

        <classes>
            <class name="com.tests.journeys.InvocationTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

AnnotationTransformer:
public class AnnotationTransformerImpl implements IAnnotationTransformer {

```
    private String invocation_key = System.getProperty("invKey");
    private String invocation_count = System.getProperty("invCount");
    //value passed from JVM is -Dkvp=invocationTest=5

    @Override
    public void transform(
         ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        String kvp = System.getProperty(invocation_key,invocation_count);
        String keyValue[] = kvp.split("=");
        if (keyValue.length != 2) {
            return;
        }
        if (!testMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(keyValue[0])) {
            return;
        }
        annotation.setInvocationCount(Integer.parseInt(keyValue[1]));
        annotation.setThreadPoolSize(5);
    }
}
```

Test class:
public class InvocationTest {

```
    @Test(invocationCount = 5)
    public void invocationTest() {

        ITestResult r = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        String methodname = r.getMethod().getMethodName();
        System.err.println(
                "Running " + methodname + "() on Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "]");

        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

The resulting test output runs the test method in parallel, on separate threads:

[image: IntelliJ_run]

How can I achieve running a method to completion before starting the next invocation? I know it will be in the documentation somewhere, just struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to google: Java multithreading.
It will give you a solution. Probably with using `Thread.join();` and other stuff.